# How to plot logistic regression model result ( sigmoid ) in python

Tags: python, plot, regression

I'm trying to plot my logistic regression model into sigmoid using python :

so my dataframe have `df['predict','actual']` where actual is (0,1) and predict is probability of being 1 ... I can plot scatter plot , but I could not figure it could how to get S-shape for sigmoid in python .. any recommendation ?

[image]

Is there a function ? I could not find one .. thanks

Comment: Do you mean a plotting function, or just the logistic function (aka softmax). That function is pretty straigthforward f(x, beta) = e^(x %*% beta) / (1 + e^(x %*% beta))

Comment: @jimmyb can you elaborate it a bit more ? i am pretty new to python..what is exactly I suppose to plug in as beta / x in here ?

Comment: So, first, I would add more sample code indicating what you have tried in python. At the moment, I can't determine whether it is plotting or logic that is causing you problems. By my answer, I was pointing out that if you can make an X,Y scatter plot in python, then making the sigmoid from a fit is simply the above function for Y values where beta is taking from the fit.